# Cross marketing the Stack Exchange sites

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-exchange

I guess this falls into a feature request of sorts as much as it is a question. I was looking over some other Stack Exchange site and discovered [3d modeling software...](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2679/3d-modelling-software-for-case-design). I thought, "this would be a good question on Super User." One thought led to another and before you know, I thought, "I wonder if there is a way to cross-reference this question on Super User?"

Is it possible to allow other Stack Exchange sites to enlist in a cooperative that allows for questions to be referenced? I see some value in even migrating questions. The mechanics of such a feature would be phenomenal, I think - but certainly do-able.

The benefits of cross-marketing the sites includes:

1. increase size of audience
2. increase site exposure & visibility
3. ...

One immediate problem I see is population of tags. It may be that instead of a full migration to SOFU, instead a ***header*** could be displayed that links to the originating site.

Comment: You may want to re-think that title...

Comment: @John C: Your wish is my command. Intentional or not, I changed it.

Comment: @Zombie - my wish is... hey, I wish for 10K rep. :)

Comment: @John C: Good luck with that. But you're up to 11 now.

Comment: @John - lol...I didn't even read it that way.

Comment: I expected that list to end with: 3. ???, 4. Profit!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

see:

http://stackexchange.com

and:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/network-central-stackexchange-com/

note that we also run house ads for the network on the anchor sites.

http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/3816/se2publicbetahousead.png

Answer (score 1):

Questions about Stack Exchange are better asked on http://meta.stackexchange.com.

But, to answer your question, Stack Exchange (which the Trilogy is part of) *will* employ more cross-promotion between sites. Each site plays a role as part of a larger, cooperative network. Association of account between sites is in the feature list. Promotion between sites with similar audiences will be a big part of drawing an audience. And issues like the migration of questions between sites will become increasingly important.